# How to cache image from was s3 url in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, amazon-s3

I had a AWS S3 image url.I want to cache the image once its downloaded in my flutter app,How can I achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: 'https://your.url',
  progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, progress) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
  placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset('images/NoImage.png'),
),
```

Or if you want to store image on your device than you can use [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) and store image to database as *Uint8List* or String bytes. Image widget has method *Image.memory* for get image from *Uint8List* which stored on your database